# Why doesn't the scaffold change color?

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Hi, I want to ask why my scaffold only changes on the AppBar. I want the whole thing to be white.

Code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
        elevation: 0.0,
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          /*padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),*/
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20, bottom: 10),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                        color: Color(0xFF021522),
                        size: 18,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const Text(
                      "Appointments",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
          child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      //margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.only(right: 20, left: 20, top: 20),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
                            blurRadius: 10.0,
                            offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0))
                      ], color: Colors.white),
                      child: _sortingHeader(),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          "Upcoming",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 20),
                        _upcomingAppointmentList.length > 0
                            ? Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              )
                            : Text(_listLoadingInfo)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have set the scaffold background to white but still no change. I've also set each container to white. Before this, after I set the background color on the scaffold, I did not experience this kind of problem. Where did I go wrong? Can anyone help me. I am new to using flutter. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `Container` that inside `SingleChildScrollView`